# Spring 3 xml parser issue -XSDException

Tags: oracle, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, xml-parsing

I have a web application where i am using spring 3.0 rest mvc .The application runs perfectly fine on my local machine. But when in deploy the war in server(tomcat 6 & java 5) the below error occurs

> Caused by: oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDException: Duplicated
>   definition for: 'identifiedType'

I Googled and found that this issue is related to  xmlparserv2.jar and this issue can be fixed by forcing the app to use apache xerces jars.

But i have not found any link explaining how to solve this issue.I do not want to changes at server level.

Can we fix these issues at application level?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved by including the  xerces jars in the POm file